# Ao mudar o valor de uma variável, todos os objetos da mesma classe estão mudando

Tags: python, pygame

Eu tenho um código que cria uma classe, com um atributo de localização, um (x, y). Eu peço para o programa criar 2 objetos dessa classe com o atributo localização aleatório ao redor de um círculo. No entanto, os dois ficam com a mesma localização.

```
import math
import pygame
from random import randint

inimigo_img = pygame.image.load('inimigo.png')
largura, altura = 640, 640


class Enemy:
    image = inimigo_img
    rect = inimigo_img.get_rect()
    rect.center = 0, 0


new_inimigo = Enemy()
ang = math.radians(randint(0, 359))
new_inimigo.rect.center = largura / 2 + 200 * math.cos(ang), altura / 2 + 200 * math.sin(ang)

new_inimigo2 = Enemy()
ang = math.radians(randint(0, 359))
new_inimigo2.rect.center = largura / 2 + 200 * math.cos(ang), altura / 2 + 200 * math.sin(ang)

print(new_inimigo2.rect.center)
print(new_inimigo.rect.center)
```

O resultado é sempre o mesmo número. Como fazer para o resultado dar números diferentes para objetos diferentes?

Comment: new_inimigo = Enemy() acho que faltou o parentese para iniciar o objeto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suas variáveis `image` e `rect` estão sendo definidas como variáveis de classe. Isso quer dizer que todo objeto criado com base naquela classe terá o mesmo valor de `image` e `rect`. Para resolver isso usando OOP, você pode definir variáveis `image` e `rect` diferentes para cada objeto criado de uma classe. Olha como você pode fazer isso:

```
class Enemy:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = inimigo_img
        self.rect = inimigo_img.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = 0, 0
```

Aqui, toda vez que você cria um objeto da classe `Enemy`, você está atribuindo uma variável `image` e uma variável `rect` especificamente para aquele objeto. Da forma antiga, as variáveis estavam sendo compartilhadas entre os objetos da classe.

O código completo com as modificações:

```
import math
import pygame
from random import randint

inimigo_img = pygame.image.load('teste.jpg')
largura, altura = 640, 640


class Enemy:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = inimigo_img
        self.rect = inimigo_img.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = 0, 0


new_inimigo = Enemy()
ang = math.radians(randint(0, 359))
new_inimigo.rect.center = largura / 2 + 200 * math.cos(ang), altura / 2 + 200 * math.sin(ang)

new_inimigo2 = Enemy()
ang = math.radians(randint(0, 359))
new_inimigo2.rect.center = largura / 2 + 200 * math.cos(ang), altura / 2 + 200 * math.sin(ang)

print(new_inimigo2.rect.center)
print(new_inimigo.rect.center)
```

Comment: muito obrigado, ajudou bastante

Answer (score 0):

Cara, consegui fazer 2 resultados diferentes mudando o nome de uma das variaveis para rreecctt, tambem exclui a variavel rect.center da sua classe, porque ela era basicamente um peso morto

```
import math
import pygame
from random import randint

inimigo_img = pygame.image.load('inimigo.png')
largura, altura = 640, 640


class Enemy:
    image = inimigo_img
    rect = inimigo_img.get_rect()



new_inimigo = Enemy()
ang = math.radians(randint(0, 359))
new_inimigo.rreecctt = largura / 2 + 200 * math.cos(ang), altura / 2 + 200 * math.sin(ang)

new_inimigo2 = Enemy()
ang = math.radians(randint(0, 359))
new_inimigo2.rreecctt = largura / 2 + 200 * math.cos(ang), altura / 2 + 200 * math.sin(ang)

print(new_inimigo2.rreecctt)
print(new_inimigo.rreecctt)
```

Comment: não é por aí - veja a resposta do @RafaelBarros para entender a diferença de atributo de classe e de instância no Python.